# Jogar valor de um grid que esta em form para outro grid em outro form C# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, gridview

Olá estou eu aqui com mais uma situação solicitando ajuda pois ainda não há encontrei nas pesquisas.
 Tenho um form que coloquei um Gridview, no form tem botão para abrir outro form de consulta e quando clicar em um item da lista ele adicione no form que já está aberto  com o grid vazio ainda segue código que estou tentando usar: 
Esse é o form inicial onde contem o botão

```
  public partial class frmPedidos : Form
{

    public frmPedidos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ConexaoClienteDataContext cc = new ConexaoClienteDataContext();

    private void btnProcSabor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        frmSlaveConsultaProduto _frmPRoduto = new frmSlaveConsultaProduto();
        if (_frmPRoduto.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;
        dgvItemPedido.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = _frmPRoduto.Codigo;
        dgvItemPedido.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value = _frmPRoduto.Valor;
    }
}
```

esse seria form de consulta e que permitirá clicar e enviar para o outro grid do form principal

```
 public partial class frmSlaveConsultaProduto : Form
{
        public int Codigo { get;  set; }
        public string Nome { get;  set; }
        public double Valor { get;  set; }
        public int quantidade { get;  set; }

    public frmSlaveConsultaProduto()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    ConexaoClienteDataContext cc = new ConexaoClienteDataContext();
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {



      Codigo=Convert.ToInt32( dgvPesquisaProd.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
       Valor = Convert.ToDouble(dgvPesquisaProd.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

    }
```

do jeito que está ele retorna um erro:

Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo trocar o evento `CellContentClick` pelo `CellMouseDoubleClick` para que o usuário dê dois cliques para selecionar o registro desejado.

O Erro de referência pode estar acontecendo porque o .Value da Cell pode ser nulo, e utilizaria o Index da Row que foi clicada. Segue código de exemplo:

```
    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >=0) //verifica se não clicou no header da coluna 
        {
            //Considerando que a Cell 0 nunca será nulo, não fiz a validação
            this.Codigo = (int)((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
        }
    }
```

Na parte do Form de Pedidos:

```
private void btnProcSabor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmSlaveConsultaProduto _frmPRoduto = new frmSlaveConsultaProduto();
    if (_frmPRoduto.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //Certeza que aqui você tem uma CurrentRow ? 

        dgvItemPedido.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = _frmPRoduto.Codigo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Então coloquei ai imagem ai assim tem com o seu exemplo mais aparentemente não está trazendo nenhum valor. Será que é porque não estou colocando o restante dos valores do grid ? mesmo eu tendo definido não obrigatório os campos?

Comment: coloque um pointbreak na linha, e verifica em tempo de execução se tem algum valor

Comment: +this{ADSIntegrados.View.frmSlaveConsultaProduto, Text: frmSlaveConsultaProduto} ADSIntegrados.View.frmSlaveConsultaProduto
  this.Codigo 7  int
  this.Valor   11     double   Aparentemente no form de seleção pegou o valor agora no form que vai receber ele recebe mais ainda da erro de referencias     --Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Comment: algum objeto que está tentando usar está nulo, basta ver qual é

Comment: será que tem alguma coisa a vê com o banco ? pois no grid que recebe ele só está para listar não fiz nada para inserir nele. Meu pensamento era adicionar nos grid e salvar apos  será que pode ser isso ?